# 2Checkout - Payment API integration

Tags: php, api, paypal, 2checkout

I am working around this: https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/sandbox/payment-api-testing

I already done the part where you generate the token. I understand the things up to this step.

I do not understand what i have to do later, how i can create the sale/charge the credit card. I am working now only with the sandbox mode.

So please tell me what i have to do next, do i have to create another post form or something else so i can proceed ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here I found the tutorial for the 2checkout payment gateway integration:-

```
https://www.codexworld.com/2checkout-payment-gateway-integration-in-php/
```